# How to generate mocks for open API spec file by using openapi-generator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

[faq-generators](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/faq-generators) says generating the server code as a starting point to implement the API backend, here are some use cases of the server generators:

mocking - easily provide an API backend for mocking based on the examples field defined in the response object.

I'm curious how to do that by using Gradle plugin for spring (did not the proper example).

Answer (score 0):

I generate a `mocks.json` based on my swagger examples in swagger.json and swager-codegen using a this mustache template:

```
{ 
    {{#apiInfo}}
        {{#apis}}"{{classname}}":
            { {{#operations}}
                {{#operation}}
                    {{#examples}}
                        "{{nickname}}": {{#example}}{{{example}}}{{/example}}{{^example}}null{{/example}}{{#hasMore}},{{/hasMore}}
                    {{/examples}}
                {{/operation}}
              {{/operations}} 
            } {{#hasMore}},{{/hasMore}}
        {{/apis}}
    {{/apiInfo}} 
}
```